# view video bitrate of a flv file in linux,how?

Tags: flv, bitrate

Is there any command to check the video bitrate of a flv file in debian/ubuntu ? I have some flv files and I want to find out their video bitrate.

I check 'file' command It only says 'Macromedia Flash Video' but no more information.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use ffmpeg:

```
ffmpeg -i filename.flv
```

Look for:

```
Input #0, flv, from 'The Veronicas - Hook Me Up.flv':
  Metadata:
    starttime       : 0
    totalduration   : 179
    totaldatarate   : 841
    bytelength      : 18910448
    canseekontime   : true
    purl            : 
    pmsg            : 
  Duration: 00:02:59.39, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 843 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (Main), yuv420p,
        640x480 [SAR 1:1 DAR 4:3], 726 kb/s, 23.98 tbr, 1k tbn, 47.95 tbc
    Stream #0:1: Audio: aac, 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s
```